# What is the difference between these two print statements in Perl? And what is the if statement doing?

Tags: perl

Code 1

```
my @ ary = ( 1, 2, 3 );   
print "size = " . @ ary . "\n" ;  
print "size = @ ary \n";
```

Code 2

```
if( $thing =~ /^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)$/ )
{
print "$1  $2  $3  $4\n";
}
```

Can you please explain me the difference between the two print commands in 'Code 1'?

And what is the code doing in the `if` statement in 'Code 2'?

Comment: Please take the time to think carefully about the whole question you want to ask before you ask it.  Also, please take the time to indent the code properly.  Select it, then press the **`{}`** button above the edit box.

Comment: Noted @JonathanLeffler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you leave the 'sigil' (the `@` symbol in this case) attached to the variable name.  However, outside of a double quoted string, you can separate them with a space.  Inside a double quoted string, there must not be a space between the sigil and the variable name.  When there is a space between the sigil and the name inside double quotes, the `@` is an `@` and the name is a string.

Additionally, in a scalar context, such as string concatenation, `@ary` produces the size of the array.

Hence, the printing produces:

```
size = 3
size = @ ary
```

Written more orthodoxly, you might have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @ary = ( 1, 2, 3 ); 
print "size = " . @ary . "\n";
print "size = @ ary\n";
print "size = @ary\n";
```

And this would produce:

```
size = 3
size = @ ary
size = 1 2 3
```

The `if` statement and its following print statement look at the string in `$thing` to see whether it is a sequence of four series of digits separated by dots and then prints out the four component numbers.  For example, if you have:

```
$thing = "192.29.36.256";
```

then it will print

```
192  29  36  256
```

and if you thought that was an I/P address, you'd almost be right, but of course it isn't actually an I/P address.  But the code would also handle `"12031.99023.23412212.23459790523"` too.

Comment: Hi @jonathan leffler, 
Can you please explain me the if block with a real time example since i couldn't get it clearly

Comment: No; SO only does batch processing — no real time.  What don't you understand?  `$thing` needs to be a variable containing a string.  If the string contains 4 groups of decimal digits, separated by dots, with no other characters in the string, then the four numbers will be printed.  For a detailed exposition, see [`perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html), and later [`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) and [`perlreref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html).  Or get and read a book on Perl (the Camel book or the Llama Book — or maybe the Alpaca book after the Llama).

Comment: One question here when you say $thing as a string do you mean we define it in " " just as we do in java ? or by string in perl you mean the same as in java " " in quotes we can have numeric as well as alpha numeric data ?

Comment: It's Perl: TMTOWTDI — there's more than one way to do it.  In my answer, I showed: `$thing = "192.29.36.256";` — what does that look like?  You could also write: `$thing = '192.29.36.256';` or `$thing = qq{192.29.36.256};` or `$thing = q(192.29.36.256);`, or `$thing = q#192.29.36.256#;` — or, if you're sadistic, `$thing = qq'192.29.36.256';` or `$thing = q"192.29.36.256";`, etc.  They're all strings; the repertoire of options includes some other alternatives too.

Comment: Cool thanks for the explanation what i meant was "192sa.232ds.1dsd.wq22" is this incorrect ?

Comment: It's a valid string, but it won't be matched by the regex in the `if` statement.  There are letters in it, and the expression only accepts digits and dots.